# Whats is systables in Guidewire?

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I start PolicyCenter in Debug Mode and console show me following message:

```
***********************************************************************
INFO Configuration.ProductModel Committing system tables file C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\underwriting_companies.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 00:57:05,561  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Committing system tables file C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\underwriting_companies.xml chunk #2
c0059               2018-04-21 00:57:05,564  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Loading C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\uw_issue_types.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 00:57:52,029  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Committing system tables file C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\uw_issue_types.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 00:58:16,916  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Loading C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\vehicle_class_codes.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 01:00:30,555  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Committing system tables file C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\vehicle_class_codes.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 01:00:30,558  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Loading C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\vehicle_industry_codes.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 01:00:31,036  INFO Server.RunLevel Memory usage: 500.824 MB used (both active and stale objects), 269.674 MB free, 770.500 MB total, 1820.500 MB max. --  Please read 'Memory usage logging' in the System Administration Guide for information on how to interpret these numbers.
c0059               2018-04-21 01:00:41,732  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Committing system tables file C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\vehicle_industry_codes.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 01:00:41,732  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Loading C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\wc_class_codes.xml
c0059               2018-04-21 01:05:50,189  INFO Configuration.ProductModel Committing system tables file C:\PolicyCenter\modules\configuration\config\resources\systables\wc_class_codes.xml


***************************************************************************
```

This is very slow, I would like to know whats are systables in Guidewire

Answer (score 4):

System tables are database tables that support business logic in PolicyCenter lines of business. 
These tables are customised with needed columns as entities in the data model. 
Product Designer is used for doing CRUD operations in these tables.

All system tables must be defined in systables.xml. 
Only system tables listed in systables.xml appear in Studio and Product Designer. 
GW loads system tables into the database at system startup.

If you do not add the system table XML file name to the systables.xml file:

```
* Studio does not recognize the file to be a resource.

* Studio does not load the system table into the database.

* Studio does not display the contents of the system table in the PolicyCenter interface.
```

If you want to control when PolicyCenter loads a particular system table, do not add the system table XML file name to systables.xml.

You then can write your own code to load the system table into the database when the system table is needed.

Within systables.xml, you can specify the order in which to load the system table XML files by using the FileDefinition Priority attribute. 
As PolicyCenter loads the product model, it loads files with a lower priority value before files with a higher priority value. 
PolicyCenter loads files with the same priority value concurrently.
The loading order is critical if there are dependencies between system tables.

-Aravind

Answer (score 1):

The logged `INFO:...` messages you see in your console are Guidewire entities that are being loaded. The list of entities loaded are defined in the `systables.xml` file which you can find by navigating to `\configuration\config\resources\systables.xml`.

One example of such entity are `underwriting companies`. If you look at the `underwriting_companies.xml` under the `systables` folder, you might find some test/dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

Please find system tables in Guidewire:

//While Debug-start all system tables commits to the local, if we made any change in 
        prior it will it will load with new Data Dictionary.

1. PC stores the system tables in the following directory:

   ```
   modules/configuration/config/resources/systables
   ```
2. PolicyCenter defines all system tables in file **systables.xml** located in Other Resources in Studio
3. Studio verifies the system table files at load time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is only loaded again after you drop your PC database. So if you move to file based h2 database, it will only load once and won't consume time until your next PC db drop.

System tables is basically a way to design "static" database tables, such as company divisions list, or taxation zones data etc. that would become invariant over subsequent database drops. 'Dictionary data' is kept in system tables and Product Designer supports editing those (because you need to create them from .xml file anyway) in some meanigful way by eg. hinting typelist values in the columns.